# jquery fadein() 'slow'

Tags: jquery, fadein

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('body').addClass('hiddencol');  //hides the body by making display:none in css
     $('body').fadeIn('slow');  
     // jQuery 1.7+       
 });
```

I tried to change `'slow'` to `'10000'`  but can't notice any difference.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a int value not a string

```
$('body').fadeIn(10000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hfDyL/)

Comment: Yes that did the trick..!! I didn't try int value, thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information:

Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings **'fast'** and **'slow'** can be supplied to indicate durations of **200** and **600 milliseconds**, respectively.

Summary:

- Fast = 200ms;
- Slow = 600ms;

For example, to get customize delay of 1000ms, you should pun integer not string of 'fast' or 'slow'.

```
$('body').fadeIn(1000); // 1 second delay
```

Comment: I know higher values indicate slower animations,thats why i asked to get even slower animations than slow,i just forgot to remove the quotes and it was rightly pointed out by @Arun P Johny

Comment: I just want to help. Glad you have already know about that. :)